# Close context implicitly in Java EE

Tags: java, wildfly, java-11, java-ee-8

I'm trying to implement the following code in Java EE 8 (Java 11) to access a datasource in Wildfly 20. The objective is to close implicitly the JNDI context and the SQL connection:

```
try (InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
     Connection conn = ((DataSource) context.lookup(pool)).getConnection()) {
    
      // use the connection

} 
catch (NamingException e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage());
} 
catch (SQLException e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage());
}
```

Problem is that context is not closeable, as I get the compilation error:

```
The resource type InitialContext does not implement java.lang.AutoCloseable
```

I'm trying to avoid adding `finally` to close the context, is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try-with-resources works only with objects that are `AutoCloseable`. One way to do this without using `finally` is by wrapping the `InitialContext` in a wrapper that implements `AutoCloseable` that performs the necessary action in its `close()` method. Something like this:

```
public class AutoCloseableWrapper implements AutoCloseable {

    private final InitialContext context;

    public AutoCloseableWrapper(InitialContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public InitialContext getContext() {
        return this.context;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        this.context.close();
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
try (AutoCloseableWrapper wrapper = new AutoCloseableWrapper(new InitialContext());
     Connection conn = ((DataSource) wrapper.getContext().lookup(pool)).getConnection()) {

    // ...
}
```